# Is firstbits.com actively mantained?

Tags: firstbits

It was [loading](http://firstbits.com) slowly, and now isn't loading at all.

I got some nasty sql error messages, I posted them to webmaster@firstbits.com but the mail bounced.

Do we know if these are temporary problems, or they might mean the site is closing down?

Comment: I don't know but in case anyone is unaware, the Firstbits concept is independent of firstbits.com, and blockchain.info also calculates Firstbits.

Comment: Even on blockchain, they aren't calculating new firstbits. This address https://blockchain.info/address/1vzzzo4PD165eCsQZE9L8xTGgz25UxMvz has been used for a while and still has no firstbits.

Comment: I am waiting to see my firstbits, '1vijay' for almost half a day.

Comment: I'm seeing the site down as well. Hopefully they come back, it was a great concept.